# How to extract or Scrape data from HTML page but from the element itself

Tags: python, lxml

Currently i use lxml to parse the html document to get the data from the HTML elements
but there is a new challenge, there is one data stored as ratings inside HTML elements

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwGle.png

```
<p data-rating="3">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star xh-highlight"></span>
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star xh-highlight"></span>
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star xh-highlight"></span>
                            </p>
```

Its easy to extract text between tags but within tags no ideas.
What do you suggest ?

Challenge i want to extract "3"
URL:https://webscraper.io/test-sites/e-commerce/allinone/computers/laptops

Br,
Gabriel.

Comment: give us your script and will check it. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question and comments correctly, the following should extract all the rating in that page:

```
import lxml.html
import requests

BASE_URL = "https://webscraper.io/test-sites/e-commerce/allinone/computers/laptops"

html = requests.get(BASE_URL)
root = lxml.html.fromstring(html.text)
targets = root.xpath('//p[./span[@class]]/@data-rating')
```

For example:

```
targets[0]
```

output

> 3

Answer (score 0):

Try below script:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

BASE_URL = "https://webscraper.io/test-sites/e-commerce/allinone/computers/laptops"

html = requests.get(BASE_URL).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
for tag in soup.find_all("div", {"class":"ratings"}):
    # get all child from the tags
    for h in tag.children:
        # convert to string data type
        s = h.encode('utf-8').decode("utf-8") 

        # find the tag with data-rating and get text after the keyword
        m = re.search('(?<=data-rating=)(.*)', s)

        # check if not None
        if m:
            #print the text after data-rating and remove last char
            print(m.group()[:-1])
```

Comment: can you give me an example with lxml??? instead of beautiful soup. because i have implemented the other part of the code with Lxml and xpath parsing over elements.

Comment: show me a portion of your script so I can help you.

Comment: I changed to soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml") and it also works

Comment: Hi sure , i would do share it  but how would you use xpath in beautiful soup??